# Three words for "test": differences?

Tags: meaning, difference

I just stumbled upon the three words `實驗` (shíyàn), `測驗` (cèyàn), and `試驗` (shìyàn). Looking them up on mdbg.net and on Google Translate, they all translate to "test/experiment". So I was wondering: what (if any) is the difference between them? Are they exact synonyms or is there a subtle difference in meaning?

PS I wss looking for [word-usage](/questions/tagged/word-usage) but it doesn't exist. I'm not sure if there are better tags for this post. If you know any, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the common definitions for these words:

實驗 - experiment (lit: practical test)
e.g. 物理實驗 - physics experiment

測驗 - test as in exam (lit: test/measure test)
e.g. 英語能力測驗 - English skill test

試驗 - test as in tryout/trial (lit: try test)
e.g. 臨床試驗 - Clinical trial

By the way, I suggest don't use any translation engine if you want to study that language, use actual dictionaries. I believe translation engines are just to get a grasp of the input. At this point in time, humans are needed to finalize the translated outputs.

Comment: So cèyàn is close to 考试, right? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: @MickG As I understand the both words, they can be interchangeable on the meanings layer, however, modern schools use 測驗 for smaller scaled tests and 考試 for greater ones.

Comment: 测验：quiz http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=quiz , 考试 examination; test; exam， http://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E8%80%83%E8%AF%95

Answer (score 3):

- 實驗: this word is commonly used to indicate scientific trials. The first character `實` means concrete, and we call a lab by appending a character for room `室` to it, which becomes "實驗室". On the other hand, a experimental theater is usually translated into "實驗劇場".
- 測驗: is normally applied to indicate examinations or assessments, such as SAT would be likely associated with this word. The character `測` means assessing.
- 試驗: is less common than the first two words, and we see this word appearing at some medical/pharmacological/agricultural areas.

They are not exact synonyms, but we would apply different terms according to related domains, so it is very rare to see `試驗` being used to indicate normal exams at schools.